# Are HTTP, web servers and web clients not used in a business environment?

Tags: discussion, support

[Do the request lines of HTTP messages now all or mostly use full URLs or path components of URLs?](https://serverfault.com/questions/953733/do-the-request-lines-of-http-messages-now-all-or-mostly-use-full-urls-or-path-co) is quickly closed, because:

> This question appears to be off-topic for this site. While what’s on-
>   and off-topic is not always intuitive, you can learn more about it by
>   reading the help center. The users who voted to close gave this
>   specific reason:
>
> "Questions on Server Fault must be about managing information technology systems in a business environment. Home and end-user
>   computing questions may be asked on Super User, and questions about
>   development, testing and development tools may be asked on Stack
>   Overflow." – yagmoth555

So are HTTP, web servers and web clients  not used in a business environment?

Superuser will not accept HTTP questions. StackOverflow is about coding questions. Neither will my question  fit.

Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

The key is that questions must be about **managing** information technology systems in a business environment.

This means we are only interested in actual technical problems you face while doing this. Fundamental questions about protocols are off-topic.

Comment: So do you expect one to solve actual technical problems without having knowledge to fundamental questions about protocols, or solve actual technical problems and never have any fundamental question about protocols?

Comment: We are not required to consider everything required for doing this as topical. Math or language questions are also off-topic, so is fundamental computer use ...

Comment: That said: Most basic protocol issues are not that interesting for system administrators anyway, while they are very important for developers (when writing server or client implementations) and I wouldn't necessarily rule out asking something like this on [SO] - when in doubt, check their help and meta site.

Comment: @Tim I've been sysadmining for a couple of decades and one thing I do know is that reding documentation is important. It's also important to read the correct documentation. In this case, a book from 2002 is not the correct documentation.

Comment: @Tim - you wrote in a comment that you cannot understand the text in the RFCs. That means that ServerFault is not a place where you'll be likely to find the answers you want - the site is populated by people who do read and understand the RFCs, and who expect the same of other professionals, which is who this site is for.

Answer (score 11):

I closed it, and for me it's borderline with another close reason, as it's could be seen as a learning recommendation.

I chooses that close reason, as like Sven told it talk about **managing**, which your question is not, and the close reason point to StackOverflow, where 'how to do an implantation of the said protocol' would be most probably talked.

A quick search lead me to like those question;

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40460179/which-are-the-specific-url-requirements-for-http-https-other-than-normal or 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers/417184#417184

Which lead to other resources, like https://url.spec.whatwg.org/ that explain the URI/URL formatting.

Please know that on ServerFault, if you manage a gear X and you don't understand the concept behind, we will most probably discuss that you would be better to call a consultant to solve an error on it or start a learning path to manage it. We can't know everything, but any downtime has a cost, and can get you fire.

Comment: I agree, this question is one that would be asked by a protocol implementer, not normally by a sysadmin (at least not without a real problem and some wireshark output).